I recently upgraded to 24.04 but that's caused an error as far as running R
Hi All: As the title says, I recently upgraded to 24.04 but started getting an error when
trying to run R.
I think it has something to do with R now looking for a different version of libcurl ?
When I try to run R, I get
/home/markleeds/bin/R-4.4.1/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libicuuc.so.72: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
So, then I said, "Let me re-install R and maybe it will link using whatever libicuuc.so is supposed to be used  ?
But, when I do that, I get below which is just a small part of the output when re-installing R  but that's where things stop.
checking for curl-config... /usr/bin/curl-config
checking libcurl version ... 8.5.0
checking curl/curl.h usability... yes
checking curl/curl.h presence... yes
checking for curl/curl.h... yes
checking if libcurl is version 7 and >= 7.28.0... no
configure: error: libcurl >= 7.28.0 library and headers are required with support for https
Thanks for any help. I spent a day on this googling for various similar problems.
I found a lot of things but I'm not very good at sys-admin so I wasn't able to fix the
problem. Thanks so much.

Rather than building from source, you may find it simpler to install the binary Ubuntu Packages For R from CRAN

Ubuntu 24.04 uses libcurl 4.8, something seems badly off.

Thank you both. I wanted to build from source because I've had a shell script that has always worked for a couple of years.  Tonight I had a message that system needs to be rebooted for upgrades. So, I rebooted, then re-ran the shell script for installing R 4.4.1 and the error was gone. My vague understanding is that rebooting somehow fixed the libcurl issue. Note though that I definitely rebooted after I upgraded to 24.04.  In fact, IIRC, the upgrade rebooted for me. Thanks to both of your for your help. I'm not sure that I would have rebooted if not for what ubfan1 said about libcurl.
